# Put text on image with Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my HTML, I have usual img element as follows:

```
<img src="images/main/car_48725.png">
```

I want to put text (to be more specific numbers) on this image, so that they can differentiate between various part of the image (it´s a car so one number should go on wheels, other on windows etc, depending on specific coordinates).

What is the way I can do this? I do not have this image inside a HTML5 canvas as I´m not using Canvas in my project.

Comment: easiest to make it a background image in a div - then you can superimpose another container (with text) on top of it.

Comment: Or he can use Map html element with car's image.

Answer (score 1):

You can position elements with transparent backgrounds on top of the image. Here's just one way:

```css
.overlap {
    position: relative;
}
.overlap img,
.overlap .text {
    position: absolute;
}
.overlap .text {
    color: blue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.x {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.y {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px
}
.z {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlap">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <div class="text x">x</div>
    <div class="text y">y</div>
    <div class="text z">z</div>
</div>
```

The container div is `position: relative` so that it's an offset parent for the elements within it. Then you can position the elements within it using `left` and `top` (in CSS, or by assigning to `someElement.style.left` and `someElement.style.top` [remember the `px` suffix]).

Comment: Or as [Kingfish points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101245/put-text-on-image-with-javascript/70101301#comment123919468_70101245), you can make the image a background.

Comment: Nice trick, but it would be more accurate if he use MAP element like I provided in my answer!

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi - No, there's nothing "more accurate" about that. It's different, is all.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `<img src="images/main/car_48725.png">` inside a `<div>` then create a label as child of the `<div>` and play with the position of the label and that´s it.

Answer (score 0):

More efficient using `MAP` element `HTML`; based on this example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)  With the help of [imagemaps](https://www.image-map.net) you can do that more fast and simple !

```js
function clicked(obj){
  console.log(obj.title)
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the wheels, the door, or the glasses  of the car to show title of it!</p>
<img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.O_8ACkiHyjX-JtYCZnCKDgHaEZ?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" alt="Kevin's_Car" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area onclick="clicked(this)" alt="front wheel" title="front wheel" href="#" coords="239,230,33" shape="circle">
    <area onclick="clicked(this)" alt="back wheel" title="back wheel" href="#" coords="411,169,30" shape="circle">
    <area onclick="clicked(this)" alt="door" title="door" href="#" coords="306,134,380,188" shape="rect">
    <area onclick="clicked(this)" alt="glass" title="glass" href="#" coords="244,88,280,92,313,98,291,138,215,122,177,107,213,82" shape="poly">
</map>
```